# Finding unique, duplicate words using Collections Java

Tags: java, collections

I'm going through Java `Collections` in [Oracle Docs Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html). I'm not able to figure out few lines of code from the below. 
This program splits the duplicate words, unique words.

```
public class FindDups {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> uniques = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> dups    = new HashSet<String>();

        for (String a : args)
            if (!uniques.add(a))
                dups.add(a);

        // Destructive set-difference
        uniques.removeAll(dups);

        System.out.println("Unique words:    " + uniques);
        System.out.println("Duplicate words: " + dups);
    }
}
```

> I'm not able to get these lines. Can anyone explain, what is actually
>   happening here?
>
> ```
> for (String a : args)
>    if (!uniques.add(a))
>        dups.add(a);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) for the `add` method of `Set`:

> `true` if this set did not already contain the specified element

So what the code does is:

1. `for (String a : args)`: Iterate over all the input strings stored in the `args` array.
2. `if (!uniques.add(a))`: If the add method returns `true`, the string is unique and successfully added to the `Set` `uniques`, as it is not contained, yet (see docs). Otherwise, the `add` method returns `false` (the current string `a` is already contained in the `Set` `uniques`) so...
3. `dups.add(a);`: ...add it to the `Set` of duplicate elements.

As a note for a beginner, a `Set` can only contain an individual element **once**. So, if `a` is already in `uniques`, the call `uniques.add(a)` will just return `true`, but **not actually add** anything. If not, the element is added and it returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs regarding [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)):

> Returns:
>   true if this set did not already contain the specified element

That means the code "tries" to insert the object into `uniques` and if the `add` returns `false` the object was already there, meaning it is actually a duplicate - therefore it gets inserted into `dups` if `uniques.add` is `false`.

Afterwards all entries in `dups` get removed from `uniques`:

```
uniques.removeAll(dups);
```

After that `uniques` only contains the Strings present only once while `dups` contains all Strings that occurred multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

```
   if (!uniques.add(a))
```

uniques.add(a) will return True if the word that was added was NOT in the set already. False if it is inside it (this method has a return of type Boolean).

```
       dups.add(a);
```

So if it sees that the word is already in the set, it will add it to the dupes set.

Hope that helps!